# Facing this issue on windows, when launch rails server

Tags: windows, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
I am totally new for ruby rails, I search more for this issue but not get any solution for windows user, all are provided for ubuntu and mac..

Comment: So, _did_ you install Postgres on your local Windows computer?

Comment: Yes, I already installed

Comment: Then you didn't start the service or supplied incorrect connection properties to your application. Can you connect using `psql`?

Comment: command psql working, what should I do now?